# Reactjs why images file converting to url string when performing delete action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

When I am performing delete action my all files converting to url string. How to prevent converting theme to url string? If I replace  `return URL.createObjectURL(file);` to  `return file;` then they are not converting from file to url string but my image are not showing. here is my code:

```
const GovtIMG = ({setImageFile}) => {
    const[voterImage,setVoterImage] = useState([])
    const onSelectFile = (e)=>{
        const selectImage = e.target.files
        const image_array = Array.from(selectImage)
        const display_url = image_array.map((file)=>{
         return URL.createObjectURL(file);
         //return file 
        })
 
      
        
        setVoterImage((image)=> image.concat(display_url))
        setImageFile((image)=> image.concat(image_array))
 
    e.target.value = ""
   }
 
   function deleteHandler(image) {
     setVoterImage(voterImage.filter((e) => e !== image));
     setImageFile(voterImage.filter((e) => e !== image));
     
     URL.revokeObjectURL(image);
   }
```

Comment: Can you be more clear. `const display_url ....` here your creating blob url of the uploaded files (image). so obviously `imageFile` will contain `File` obj & `voterImage` blob url.
So what are you asking exactly?

Comment: If I delete any file then all file inside my setvoterimage array becomes file to string url.

Answer (score 0):

```
setImageFile(voterImage.filter((e) => e !== image));
```

In this line, your filtering `voterImage` not `imageFile` file. thats why `File`s are turning to string blob urls. And you cant filter `File` obj with `image` url! you will have to do it some other way.

Probably by, removing `setVoterImage` concept totally, and creating the blob url in the component, and pass `File` to that component. so, when it ejects it will revoke the blob url, and you will have `File` obj which you can use to filter out the `setImageFile`

```
const GovtIMG = ({ setImageFile }) => {
    const [voterImage, setVoterImage] = useState([]);
    const onSelectFile = (e) => {
        const selectImage = e.target.files;
        const image_array = Array.from(selectImage);
        const display_url = image_array.map((file) => {
            return URL.createObjectURL(file);
            //return file    //<--- here your not returning `File`!!!, so `setVoterImage` will always have blob url
        });

        setVoterImage((image) => image.concat(display_url));
        setImageFile((image) => image.concat(image_array)); // <--- here `setImageFile` is assigned with `File` not string blob url!!

        e.target.value = "";
    };

    function deleteHandler(image) {
        setVoterImage(voterImage.filter((e) => e !== image)); //<-- so, its works
        setImageFile(voterImage.filter((e) => e !== image)); //<-- problem!!, explained above

        URL.revokeObjectURL(image);
    }
}
```

hope it helps.